# What's a "Ch" in MSVC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lines

I was thinking about my code, and I accidentally clicked the `Ln 74` at the bottom of the MSVC++ window.  I got a screen that said `Line number (1 - 136):`, and it jumped the cursor to the line I entered.  When I click the `Col 1` or `Ch 1` I get the same screen.

I know `Ln 74` means I'm on line 74, and `Col 1` means I'm on column 1, but what does `Ch 1` mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Character 1?

Comment: Yup, most likely character when used in that context!

Answer (score 2):

As Paul wrote, it is probably character.  The difference between column and character being due to the width of tabs.  A tab is one character that can occupy multiple columns.